# Embracing and debracing Greek passages

Tags: regular-expression

I need two commands: one to find all occurences of `\gr{...}` and
remove the `\gr{` and `}`, leaving the contents `...`, which
should work accross lines; and another to find all strings
consisting of
Greek characters (unicode ranges 0x0370--0x03ff and
0x1f00--0x1fff), AND non-Latin punctuation characters, AND TeX
commands (words precedes by `\`),  (the last is not terribly
importaint, as there will be few places to correct manually
without it), and embrace them with `\gr{` and `}`.

This is what I have tried:

```
 " Greek and Coptic or Greek Extended
 let g = '[\u370-\u3ff\u1f00-\u1fff]'
 let G = '[^\u370-\u3ff\u1f00-\u1fff]'
 let GL = '[^\u370-\u3ff\u1f00-\u1fffA-Za-z]'
 let ACn = '%([^A-Za-z%]|\n)'
 " replacement string
 let r1 = '\1\\gr{\2}\3'
 let r = r1

 let p3 = '\v%(^|(\a'.GL.'*))('.g.ACn.'*'.g.')(\A*\w)'
 let p = p3

 let tgr3 = 'v/\\in\=de\=x/s/'.p.'/'.r.'/g'
 let tgr = tgr3

 command! GrClear %s/\v\\gr\{(\_[^}]*)\}/\1/g
 command! GrInsert norm ,<c-r>=tgr<cr><cr>
```

It works to an extent, but not great.  Any pointers in the right
direction will be greatly appreciated.---And I do apologize that
this attempt is poorly explained, and that I haven't explained
exactly what the fail cases are: it's been a while since I did
this, and I just wanted to see if this might be familiar and
simple to someone; otherwise, ignore it and I will post a better
question when I have more time. Thanks.

PS.  I am now using

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
binmode STDIN,  ":utf8";
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
my $g=qr/[\x{0370}-\x{03FF}\x{1F00}-\x{1FFF}]/;
my $L=qr/[^a-zA-Z]/;
while (<>)
{
    s/( (?: $g $L* $g) )/\\gr{$1}/xg;
  print
}
```

which must be called with the cmd-line option `-0`. this works fine except a minor aesthetic problem: the pattern doesn't know whether a bracket at the end of it belongs inside or not.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, have you tried vim's *di{* command to delete inside curly braces? It's less readable than what you have, but to remove \gr{xxx} leaving the xxx I would have written something like

```
:set lazyredraw
/\\gr{
qq3ldi{pd5hnq
```

then typed *@q* a few times to check, and then done *1000@q* or *10000@q* a few times as necessary to take care of the rest.